# What is a bileue?

Tags: etymology, middle-english

I was looking up the word "god" in the Oxford English Dictionary On-Line, which led me to this entry:

> **d. *the god of this world*** : the Devil, Satan.
>
> c1384   *Bible* (Wycliffite, E.V.) (Douce 369(2)) (1850) 2 Cor. iv. 4
>   In whiche the God of this world hath blyndid the soules of men out of
>   the bileue.

What is a bileue?

Comment: It looks like *"believe"*; *"u"* was used for *"v"* back then. And 2 Corinthians 4:4 says *"The god of this age has blinded the minds of unbelievers"*.

Comment: The words *out of the bileue* are followed immediately by *", or unfeithful men,"*. I think @PeterShor is right.

Comment: I should point out that the *"u"* = *"v"* in *bileue* is now an *"f"*. The OED shows that the forms of the noun with *"f"* and *"v"* coexisted in Middle English, but the *"f"* eventually won out.

Answer (score 3):

29 Jhesu seith to him, Thomas, for thou hast seyn me, thou **bileuedist**;
blessid ben thei, that syjcu not, and ban **bileuyd**.

Jesus saith unto him, Thomas, because thou hast seen me, thou hast **believed**: blessed are they that have not seen, and yet have **believed**.

31 Forsothe thes ben writun, that je **bileue**, for Jhesu is Crist, the sone of
God, and that je **bileuynge** haue lyf in his name.

But these are written, that ye might **believe** that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God; and that **believing** ye might have life through his name.

-The Gothic and Anglo-Saxon Gospels in parallel